# CSV parse from NSMutableURLRequest misses first 150 rows

Tags: ios, xcode, csv, core-plot

I'm reading a `.CSV` file on a server using `NSMutableURLRequest` and when I did CSV parsing of the data, I end up reading the plot points incomplete. For example if i have 300 plus rows the app reads it from 150th plus row. Any suggestion on how to approach this? Is there a function that stores the value of the plot points? Sorry I'm new to iOS. Thanks much for the help

```
  - (id) init
{
// regular [super init], etc. etc.
   NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(_connectionTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
// other custom initialization continues
    return self;
}

 -(void)serverConnect{
           NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL/test.csv"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:15.0];

             NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

         }


 - (void) _connectionTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
           [self serverConnect];
       }

 -(void)connection :(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
         response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     }

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {


         NSString *stripped1 = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];

         NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[stripped1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
         NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[rows count]]; 
         NSMutableArray *contentArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[rows count]];
         NSArray *components;

         for (int i=0;i<[rows count]; i++) {

           if(i == 0 || [[rows objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]){
            continue;
            }
           components = [[rows objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

         id x = [components objectAtIndex:0] ;
         id y = [components objectAtIndex:1];
         id z = [components objectAtIndex:2];

        [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x,@"X",y,@"Y", nil]];
        [contentArray1 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x,@"X",z,@"Y", nil]];
    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [_graphHostingView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2000, 1000)];
   _graphHostingView.scrollEnabled = YES;
   _graphHostingView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
   _graphHostingView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;



   [self init];
   //[self serverConnect];

}
```

variable response is `NSString`. Will it be better if i use `MSMutableString` or `NSMutableArray` ?
If not can anyone explain how `-(NSArray *)numbersForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;` method helps? Does it help me save the plot data ? So next  can I just load it when the core plot is used to plot? Is the use of timer affecting the data that is being read?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using stringWithContentsOfURL rather than the method you're using to pull the data from the server. I would assume that is where the problem occurs and your end goal is to get all the data into a string anyways so it would be a more efficient method for doing so.